# Client able to connect to Hbase DB without including hbase-site.xml in classpath

Tags: java, configuration, hbase

I am using java client to connect to Hbase DB configured in standalone mode.Its hbase-site.xml is :

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/vimal/HBASE/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/vimal/HBASE/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

In my client code, i am using HtablePool to get an instance of HTable. Everything works fine but my question is i havent included hbase-site.xml in my classpath so how does my client connects to HbaseDB. Its very strange to me. Please help here.

Comment: Does this work because i have set $HBASE_HOME variable and so HBaseConfiguration.create() will use this variable to locate hbase-site.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your `hbase-site.xml` any option directly related to HBase connection.
Probably your setup perfectly works based on default configuration which is common case.

- `hbase.rootdir` - just related to user 'home' dir on cluster (no
  relation to connection).
- `hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir` - at all    does not have direct
  relation to HBase connection.

Comment: sorry .. i have updated my hbase-site.xml .. could you please elaborate more on this ?

Comment: Is it necessary to set HBAsE_HOME variable or its just for comfort ?

Comment: Its another question, don't mix questions so later people cannot find answers). OK, its set by `hbase-config.sh` which is called by `hbase` so you don't have to set it.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks Roman .. But still i am unable to understand whole process. Documentation  and other books say that client ( Java program accessing Hbase ) should have hbase-site.xml in its classpath or i should provide Zookeeper information explicitly in the configuration object.I am not doing either so how does my java program connects to Hbase instance correctly ? Is it because by default it connects to localhost for zookeeper at port 2181 ?

Comment: Yes, for example, default configuration for zookeeper quorum in most cases is `localhost:2811` which suits most of local one node installations. Almost the same is for HDFS and JobTracker.